# Huawei e303c data-card not working for Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, usb-modem, mobile-broadband, huawei

Cheers to you.
I got a problem in making a Mobile-BroadBand connection in Ubuntu 11.04, using '**Huawei e303c**' usb data-card. I'm using Tata Docomo 3G sim-card (India, circle: Maharastra).

**My observations**:

1. I installed the device's driver 'Mobile-Partner For Linux'(which came up with the device). But it is not detecting my device.
2. In Network Manager, Adding a Mobile-BroadBand connection is not able to detect the device (with or without the device's driver installed).
3. I tried softwares like usb_modeswitch, gnomeppp, wvdial, sakis3G and followed their guidelines. These too didn't work.
4. Without the driver, the system is able to identify the device (Mobile-Partner icon comes-up, that leads to driver setup files). But after installing the driver, nothing comes-up there.
5. In all the above cases, when '*lsusb*' cmd is fired, the prompt shows the connected data card (as 'DEVICE_ID:VENDOR_ID Huawei Technologies Ltd.,').

This is my problem. Give a solution to get my device connected.

-Umash

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Is there any help?

Comment: :) i tried many of the tips and tricks posted on various sites. Sometimes 'wvdial' worked. But when i upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 everything went well. Just insert the device, the remaining will be taken care of by the OS (just follow the prompts). I think when it comes to Ubuntu-11.04/11.10 there are some OS/patch issues in detecting the wireless broad-band modem.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem. Earlier the datacard was working fine with Ubuntu 12.04, without installing any software. But as soon as I installed the linux drivers which were bundled with the device, it stopped working.

After a lot of searching, and digging into the install script, I found a simple solution. Run the following commands in the terminal, to get Huawei E303c working again:

```
sudo apt-get remove usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch
```

These commands will reinstall usb-modeswitch. Actually, the whole problem arises because Huawei drivers modify the usb-modeswitch data files, reinstalling them will solve the issue.

Comment: No this didn't work..Still for 'lsusb' cmd the modem (Huawei e303c) is showing up but not detected by network manager. Even attempts using 'Sakis3G' fails!

Comment: Thanks a ton!, this works like magic even on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I followed the 2 commands you told, then what to do?

Comment: I did this back in 2012 with Ubuntu 12.04, don't know if it will work in more recent ubuntu distribution

Comment: @Pankaj sir, thanks a lot, just followed your instruction after wasting 6 hours and now works like charm!... i am using `ubuntu x64 15.04` :) +1

Comment: would like to add one more point, after ejecting or removing the data card, i have to run both the commands again and need to uninstall & install the drivers again to make it work... :(