# Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131 contains software intended to be automatically started. Wifi doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, usb, internet

Suddenly for a reason I do not know, my USB wifi stopped working on Ubuntu  but still works on Windows. I get this message when I plug it to Ubuntu laptop:

> “NamBe” contains software intended to be automatically started. Would
>   you like to run it? If you don’t trust this location or aren’t sure,
>   press Cancel.

When I press on Run, it shows this error instead:

> Unable to locate the program

This USB Wifi is still working well on an other laptop where I have Windows 10 though.

How to fix this?

**EDIT 1:**

- [Output of](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23301876/) `sudo fdisk -l` without the adapter being plugged
- [Output of](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23301882/) `sudo fdisk -l` after plugging the adapter

**EDIT 2:** (for user.dz)

- [Output of](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23302020/) `lsusb` without the adapter being plugged
- [Output of](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23302025/)  `lsusb` with the adapter being plugged

P.S. I will edit later this post to respond to the other comments too

Comment: It looks like your Huwei Hilink includes some flash storage Please [edit] your post to include the difference between `sudo fdisk -l` with and without the device plugged in

Comment: @avazwij, would you add output of `lsusb` . Unplug the device, run `udevadm monitor`, plug it again, post its output too.

Comment: Also please send output of `dmesg`.

Comment: @avazwij, it seems to me a usb-modeswitch problem. After you get the requested outputs above, try this solution http://askubuntu.com/a/156594/26246 .

Comment: Are you sure you don't have those links backwards? I've seeing a /dev/sdb on the "after plugging the adapter" link and not on the "without the adapter being plugged" (fdisk -l section)

Comment: Based on a review of the comments I concur with @user.dz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're solving the wrong problem here. Why run the script when you can just have the system auto-detect your modem and Just Work™.

If you run a `modeswitch` command on the modem, it will activate itself as a modem instead of mass storage, and you system will automatically detect it as such.

Reading your `lsusb` output, we have this:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131 (Mass storage mode)
```

So, let's make the mode auto-set to modem mode. In a terminal, run the following command:

```
sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

At the very bottom of the opened file, paste in this exact string:

```
# Huawei E353/E3131
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="1f01", RUN +="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

Unplug your modem and reboot the system. Upon restart, plug in the modem. The system should automatically detect it as a modem and connect you to the internet. You won't need to auto-run anything, and you won't have the partition mounted on your computer.

<sup>[(source)](https://askubuntu.com/a/813385/208574)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Your `sudo fdisk -l` output with the adapter unplugged contains the following at line 112:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3,7 GiB, 4003463168 bytes, 7819264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     8064 7819263 7811200  3,7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

The output with your adapter unplugged ends at line 107.

---

### Edit 1 - New Information from OP

Here is a screenshot of USB files:

[image: USB Startup]

In order to disable auto-run of the USB (generating the error message) go to `System Settings`, `Details`, `Removable Media` and check the last box to never auto-run inserted media:

[image: Removable Media]

This should make the error message go away when the USB is inserted.

Comment: @avazwij So your USB WiFi stick serves dual purpose as /dev/sdb (flash drive) with 4 GB of space.?

Comment: In previous months, it worked ONLY as a WiFi adapter. Now that it stopped worked suddenly on Ubuntu 16, it looks like my computer thinks it is a USB for storage and not for connecting to internet. But on Windows it still works fine just as a WiFi adapter and not a USB storage. Thank you

Comment: If you don't know what files are stored on it can you run the command  `pmount /dev/sdb1` and list the files on it?

Comment: I can not delete AUTORUN.INF because all the content is ready only. Thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your file listing. Notice there is an `install_linux` in your screen shot. Perhaps you need to rerun this after installation of Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The pop-up messages do not appear now after I did what you sugested, but I do not get Internet connexion yet. Thank you.

Comment: @avazwij Can you post the contents of `Install_linux` from your USB stick?