# D-Link Modem in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS not being detected

Tags: networking, wireless, usb-modem, modem, d-link

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS along with Windows 7.

Though the installation worked fine,I am unable to do Internet from there.

I do Internet using D-Link Modem where the system requirements are Ubuntu 10.04 or higher.

So it should be compatible with mine,but why is not being detected ?

I have run the command **lsusb** and I have found it has been listed as **D-Link Corp.**

Please suggest some remedies.

I did go the networking icon,set the *mobile broadband* option and set the APN of the mobile operator and operator as *Vodafone Connect*,but still it's not detected .

**EDITS**

**`lsusb`**

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 2001:a407 D-Link Corp.
```

**On removing modem**

**`dmesg -w`** gives

```
[ 1063.191885] usb 2-1.3: Product: D-Link DWP-157
[ 1063.191889] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: D-Link,Inc  
[ 1063.191894] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 531399703353630
[ 1063.192657] usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1063.192843] scsi host12: usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0
[ 1064.190463] scsi 12:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HSPA USB SCSI CD-ROM      6225 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 1064.193317] sr 12:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
[ 1064.195881] sr 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 1064.196297] sr 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[ 1064.447249] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[ 1064.448975] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
[ 1165.250481] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 9
```

On plugging again:

**`dmesg -w`**

```
[ 1064.196297] sr 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[ 1064.447249] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[ 1064.448975] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
[ 1165.250481] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 1250.773650] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[ 1250.867819] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2001, idProduct=a407
[ 1250.867830] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 1250.867836] usb 2-1.3: Product: D-Link DWP-157
[ 1250.867841] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: D-Link,Inc  
[ 1250.867845] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 531399703353630
[ 1250.868612] usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1250.868812] scsi host13: usb-storage 2-1.3:1.0
[ 1251.867201] scsi 13:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HSPA USB SCSI CD-ROM      6225 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 1251.869953] sr 13:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
[ 1251.870493] sr 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 1251.870854] sr 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[ 1252.147458] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[ 1252.148686] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
```

On plugging the modem:

**`udevadm monitor -u`**

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing

UDEV  [1250.415969] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [1250.428842] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1250.433148] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host13 (scsi)
UDEV  [1250.437686] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host13/scsi_host/host13 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [1251.408929] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host13/target13:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [1251.409064] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/11:1 (bdi)
UDEV  [1251.414972] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [1251.423177] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/bsg/13:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [1251.423899] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/scsi_device/13:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [1251.425856] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [1251.529367] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
UDEV  [1251.636974] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
```

**ADDED**

Look for default devices ...
   product ID matched

Found devices in default mode (1)

Access device 004 on bus 002

Error opening the device. Abort

Please guide me here by giving some steps.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add more info, what is its model? Add output of `sudo lsusb`? Unplug it, run these command in separate terminals: `udevadm monitor -u` & `dmesg -w`, plug it, then post the output of both commands.

Comment: Yes I will do it ;please wait @user.dz

Comment: @user.dz;I have edited it ;I have run the commands given by you also but I can't post the output here because the output is very large

Comment: Add `lsusb` D-Link line directly to the question. For other outputs , post only new lines. Or use http://paste.ubuntu.com and add its link to the question.

Comment: @user.dz;I have added an edit;Please guide me now

Comment: Seems a modeswitch issue, try this answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/835348/26246

Comment: I have tried that but not of any use;Would be glad if you could post an answer@user.dz

Answer (score 0):

This is [2nd answer trial](https://askubuntu.com/posts/860678/revisions), I could find this device `2001:a407` add in last package for zesty (Ubuntu 17.04 under development). As you can see in `/usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz` / `2001:a407`

```
# D-Link DWM-157 C1
TargetVendor=0x2001
TargetProduct=0x7d0e
StandardEject=1
```

To install the last package

1. Download it from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=zesty&searchon=names&keywords=modeswitch)

   ```
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch-data/usb-modeswitch-data_20160803-1.is.really.20160803-1_all.deb
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch/usb-modeswitch_2.4.0+repack0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```

   If you have different architecture, open the above link and download the correct one.
2. Install them

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i usb-modeswitch*.deb
   ```
3. Reboot the machine

   ```
   reboot
   ```

Alternatively, a one liner

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch-data/usb-modeswitch-data_20160803-1.is.really.20160803-1_all.deb; wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch/usb-modeswitch_2.4.0+repack0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb; sudo dpkg -i usb-modeswitch*.deb
```

Comment: Sorry nothing is working ;I am finding it difficult to understand what are the commands sequentially to be written;Can you give a step by-step process

Comment: I ran as you said ;the outputs of the first two are the same as posted ,the 3rd one saidLook for default devices ...
   product ID matched
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 004 on bus 002
Error opening the device. Abort

Comment: Which command should i run first in the terminal?can u please tell that seqentially

Comment: Sorry to say no commands  are working ;the first one says "Not a directory" the second says "error processing code"

Comment: Please tell me if you need any information you need

Comment: @BenStokes, try again , added wget installtion, but It should be already installed by default.

Comment: What should I do first ?Should I run the command starting with /usr...

Comment: And then run sudo...

Comment: How can I download from packages..

Comment: @BenStokes, the that `/usr/..` is not a command. I resumed answer as  one liner to run  then reboot